# ROS Diamondback and archlinux: some of yaourt's and pacman's output suppressed?

Tags: ros, rosdep, rosinstall, archlinux, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I encountered some difficulty with installing ROS dependencies on Archlinux (via --dep-install). The output of the interactive `pacman` and `yaourt` sessions does not appear in full length in the terminal (the questions are not printed to the terminal). I managed to blindly answer the questions  by `yaourt` and `pacman` and thus install ROS diamondback on arch. I tested this on two different Arch installations.

Did anyone else notice this phenomenon, or even knows of a workaround?

Here is a screenshot of the output, notice the questions for the root password, and the questions whether to proceed with the installation - they are both not printed (pasting terminal output to another window shows that it's not just an issue of terminal colors):

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10932/ros-diamondback-and-archlinux:-some-of-yaourt%27s-and-pacman%27s-output-suppressed?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug in the implementation. In the debian/apt implementation the flags are passed to make it non interactive.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0